# How can I fix this simple program?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written this very simple program in python:

```
a=input('Enter the grade:')

if int(a)<5:
    print('D')
elif 5<=int(a)<10:
    print('c')
elif 10<=int(a)<15:
    print('B')
elif 15<=int(a)<=20:
    print('A')
elif 20<int(a):
    print('You idiot !')

else :
    print('Write a  number idiot !')
```

And the program will work if the user write a number, but if they write a string the program will give this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Grader.py", line 2, in <module>
    if int(a)<5:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'h'
```

How can I change the program, so that the users can write anything they want!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are exactly trying to do? What are your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: By the way. Calling users idiots would be a reason for me to fire somebody.

Comment: Well i'm not your employee ! and that is an exercise program for beginners like me which my friend decided to make it a little fun ! do you think , we would call users idiot in a real program (like a project which we later have to write at the end of the semester) ?

Answer (score 1):

modify:

```
a=input('Enter the grade:')
```

to:

```
a = None
while not a:
    try:
        a = int(input('Enter the grade:'))
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter a valid integer!)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: What if they type `0` ?

Comment: @khelwood good catch, here you go :)

Comment: Why not just `while True`? Also, if you don't use `e`, then no need `as e`.

Comment: @KevinGuan you can do while True, indeed it saves you one character but doesn't explain what are we waiting for to happen in the while loop. As for `e`, true - I'll modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can ether check the type of the variable or do a try / except.  (Last is the easiest way, and see sufficiënt here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check whether the input value is an integer or not:

```
In [1]: def is_int(value):
...:     try:
...:         int(value)
...:         return True
...:     except ValueError:
...:         return False
...:     

In [2]: is_int(6)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: is_int('something')
Out[3]: False
```

Hope this helps!